# cant run test in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, gallio, testdriven.net

i am using visual studio 2012. i installed test driven personal beta 2. then i installed gallio bundle 3.2.

however, when i am running a test, it fails. the output says this:

```
  It looks like you're trying to execute a Gallio/MbUnit unit test.

  For Gallio v3.0.6 build 787 / Gallio v3.1 build 313 or above (recommended):
  Please ensure that the directory containing your 'MbUnit.dll' reference also contains     Gallio's
  test runner files ('MbUnit.dll.tdnet', 'TDNet\Gallio.TDNetRunner.dll', 'Gallio.dll' etc.)

  For earlier versions:
  You need to install Gallio (after TestDriven.Net) using its MSI installer.

  You can find Gallio downloads and support here:
  http://www.gallio.org/
```

i am not sure what is the problem. for those who are using visual studio 2012, which versions of testdriven and gallio you are using?

UPDATE:
I checked the said dlls if it is in the same folder with MbUnit.dll and they are. what is the problem?? T T

Comment: Gallio does not support the VS2012 test runner.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515337/2212458