# Using Gallio to run vstest from VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sonarqube, gallio

I am surprised that I have not been able to find this information online.  We use Sonar to run Gallio to collect test coverage information.  When Gallio runs it reports the following error.

```
Cannot run tests because the MSTest executable was not found
```

Now we use Visual Studio 2012.  The test runner is no longer mstest, but is instead vstest.console.exe.  Can Gallio use the Visual Studio 2012 test runner, and if so, then how do I set that up?

Comment: You should try to do it first, then come back and ask a more specific question if you fail.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I HAVE tried it.  Where do you think the error message given in the question came from?

Comment: `Can Gallio use the Visual Studio 2012 test runner, and if so, then how do I set that up?` <-- This is your question, which also makes it sound like you haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gallio only uses *MSTest.exe* to run tests so you need to at least have the VS2010 test agents installed execute tests: https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=899

Gallio does not have the ability to use the Visual Studio test runner at this time which means you cannot use things like *Fakes* in your unit tests which *MSTest.exe* does not know how to instrument. Although many VS2012/2013 tests will run successfully with *MSTest.exe*, new features will fail unless run with vstest.console.exe which needs to be implemented as an extension in Gallio to work correctly: https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=923

If you just need Gallio to run your unit tests written in VS2012, install the test agents to make *MSTest.exe* available to Gallio to run the tests. If you want Gallio to use *vstest.console.exe* and make use of new test features that *MSTest.exe* are not capable of running, you will need to wait for this extension to be added to Gallio (or contribute it yourself).

Comment: Thanks.  Requiring additional test agents to support Gallio can be a blocker to it use.  I'm surprised efforts to support the 2012 test runner does not show up more prominently anywhere.