# How to use OpenCover plugin Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opencover

I tried to generate code coverage xml file. but i failed

after adding the Nuget packages and enabled Nuget Package Restore on the solution.
then open cmd and run this command
.\packages\OpenCover.4.5.1604\OpenCover.Console.exe^
 -register:user^
 -target:MSTest.exe^
 -targetargs:"/noresults /noisolation /testcontainer:..\releases\Latest\NET40\MonitoredUndoTests.dll"^
 -filter:+[*]*^
 -output:.\report\output.xml

but always generate an error

Comment: error is Target 'MSTest.exe' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try following link that worked for me. It says Gallio error but it is using OpenCover to run the coverage. I was using Gallio with Sonar and running OpenCover and using these steps fixed my issue.

[Gallio error : MSTest executable was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999474/gallio-error-mstest-executable-was-not-found)

Comment: but, i don't use sonar for this coverage, 
so do you expect it work without sonar

Comment: Please add me on skype to discuss it please if you can
osama.yasser@outlook.com it's my skype account

Comment: I can't come on Skype... Did you try the steps mentioned in that answer?

Comment: yes, after trying these steps.
i try this command 

OpenCover.4.5.2316\OpenCover.Console.exe^
 -register:user^
 -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"^
 -targetargs:"/noresults /noisolation /testcontainer:C:\src\FileBound\source\V6.Core.Web\bin\FileBoundV6.dll"^
 -filter:+[*]*^
 -output:C:\report\output.xml

but i have no result it say no tests to execute
you have any idea

Comment: Try looking at the output file overcover creates. you should see error message there. I think its an xml file.